# Does Hazelcast have timeout support for cache items?

Tags: caching, hazelcast

I need a distributed cache which have timeout support. Can we give timeout limits to distributed Hazelcast Map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about TTL (time to live) of the cached elements you'll find information about it here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#map-eviction

Comment: Thanks @noctarius. That's what i asked.